# How to fill the different elements of a matrix in python

Tags: numpy, matrix

I want to have a 2D Matrix and then fill the elements of this matrix with different values. I know that I need to create a matrix first with the following definition:

Matrix = np.zeros(10,10)
Now my question is how I can fill of the elements of this matrix by a value lets say the element of [4][7] with value of 5. Thanks

Comment: best use `are[i, j] = value` syntax when indexing.  A do read more of the numpy docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful, because the right sintax for a 10x10 matrix filled by zeros is `Matrix = np.zeros((10,10))`. Then you can simply write in a different line `Matrix[4][7] = 5`. I advice you to read a tutorial or a introductory book on Python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to do that in a for loop, this is how it looks like: my_matrix = np.zeros ((length, length)) for i, j in my_list :                                                 the length can be for example 5, and my list are the pair of indices. Now I want to fill the different elements by a fix value

Comment: @ash if the elements of my_list are of the kind [index1, index2], then you can write: for index in my_list: Matrix[index[0]][index[1]] = value

Comment: By the way I am using Python 2.7, for index, do I need to call any specific module rather than NumPy? Because it is not working

Comment: it says "index" may be undefined

Comment: @ash how did you define my_list? a solution without variables is for i in range(0,10): for j in range(0,10): Matrix[i][j] = value. Careful with the indentation.